# magento 2 elastic search disk space

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2

I am fairly new to Magento 2 and elastic search. I have configured elastic search with Magento 2 we have less than 200 products and the elastic search instance consumed 160Gb of disk space. I see a lot of indices like:

```
magento2_default_tracking_log_session_20180502
magento2_default_tracking_log_event_20180504
```

I see category catalog index and product catalog indices which are very small (as expected). what are above indices? can I remove those and avoid them from being generated again? How can I reduce disk space usage?

Kind Regards

Sajid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, the full answer to the question is here : https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/issues/912